# I can't find the error in my c++ matrix calculator program

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I am working on a matrix calculator. Currently I am focused on the addition and subtraction functions.

The way the program works is that it creates a vector of vectors to represent the matrices. I have finished writing the addition and subtraction functions but for some reason, every time I try to use them, after I input the 2 matrices, the program lags then crashes.

When I compile it, I receive no syntax errors, so it's probably a logical error. I have tried going through my code to find the error but I still can't find it.

**Please help me find why it lags then crashes after inputting the 2 matrices when adding or subtracting.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h> // for _getch
std::vector < std::vector<double> > matrix_1;
std::vector < std::vector<double> > matrix_2;
int rows_1;
int columns_1;
int rows_2; //This is for the second matrix when multiplying
int columns_2; //This is for the second matrix when multiplying
std::vector < std::vector<double> > result; //This is for storing the result
int operation;//This variable is for the user to choose the operation
double input;//This is for the user input for the values inside the Matrices
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//The below function is for being to able to give input without inserting a new line
double get_input()
    {std::string word ="";
    char c = _getch();
    while (not(std::isspace(c)))
        {word.push_back(c);
        std::cout<<c;
        c=_getch();
        }
    std::cout<< c;
    input = std::stod(word);
    return input;}
//The below function is for creating a matrix
std::vector < std::vector<double> > create_matrix(std::vector < std::vector<double> > matrix, int rows, int columns){
    for (int i =0; i<rows; i++)
            {std::vector<double> row ={};
            for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++){
                if (rows==1 and columns==1){
                    std::cout<<"[ ";
                    input = get_input();
                    row.push_back(input);
                    std::cout<<"]"<<"\n";}
                else if ((j==0 and i==0) or (j==0 and i==(rows-1)))
                {std::cout<<"[ ";
                input = get_input();
                row.push_back(input);
                std::cout<<" ";}
                else if ((j==(columns-1) and i==0) or (j==(columns-1) and i==(rows-1)))
                {input = get_input();
                std::cout<<" ]"<<"\n";
                row.push_back(input);}
                else if (j==0){ std::cout<<"| ";
                                input= get_input();
                                row.push_back(input);
                                std::cout<<" ";}
                else if (j==(columns-1)){input = get_input();
                                    std::cout<<" |";
                                    row.push_back(input);
                                    std::cout<<"\n";}
                else {input = get_input();
                    row.push_back(input);
                    std::cout<<" ";}
                    }
            matrix.push_back(row);
            }
    return matrix;}
//This function is for addition
void add(){
    std::cout<<"Insert the amount of rows (horizontal - ) there are: ";
    std::cin >> rows_1;
    std::cout<<"Insert the amount of columns (vertical | ) there are: ";
    std::cin >> columns_1;
    std::cout<<"\nENTER EACH NUMBER IN THE FIRST MATRIX SEPARATED BY A SPACE\n\n";
    create_matrix(matrix_1, rows_1, columns_1);
    std::cout<<"\nNow for the creation of the second matrix\n";
    create_matrix(matrix_2, rows_1, columns_1);
    //Creating the result matrix
    result={};
    for (int i=0; i<rows_1; i++)
    {std::vector<double> row = {};
    for (int j=0; j<columns_1; j++)
    {row.push_back((matrix_1[i][j]+matrix_2[i][j]));}
    result.push_back(row);}
    //Printing the result matrix
    std::cout<<"\nHere is the result: \n";
    for (int i=0; i<rows_1; i++)
    {for (int j=0; j<columns_1; j++)
    {if (rows_1==1 and columns_1==1){std::cout<<"[ "<<result[0][0]<<" ]\n";}
    else if ((i==0 and j==0) or (i==(rows_1-1) and j==0)){std::cout<<"[ "<<result[i][j]<<" ";}
    else if ((i==0 and j==(columns_1-1)) or (i==(rows_1-1) and j==(columns_1-1))) {std::cout<<result[i][j]<<" ]\n";}
    else if (j==0){std::cout<<"| "<<result[i][j]<<" ";}
    else if (j==(columns_1-1)) {std::cout<< result[i][j] <<" |";}
    else {std::cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";}}
    }
    }

//This is another function that will do the subtraction. It is the same as the addition one, only that corresponding values are subtracted
void subtract(){
    std::cout<<"Insert the amount of rows (horizontal - ) there are: ";
    std::cin >> rows_1;
    std::cout<<"Insert the amount of columns (vertical | ) there are: ";
    std::cin >> columns_1;
    std::cout<<"\nENTER EACH NUMBER IN THE FIRST MATRIX SEPARATED BY A SPACE\n\n";
    create_matrix(matrix_1, rows_1, columns_1);
    std::cout<<"\nNow for the creation of the second matrix\n";
    create_matrix(matrix_2, rows_1, columns_1);
    //Creating the result matrix
    result={};
    for (int i=0; i<rows_1; i++)
    {std::vector<double> row = {};
    for (int j=0; j<columns_1; j++)
    {row.push_back((matrix_1[i][j]-matrix_2[i][j]));}
    result.push_back(row);}
    //Printing the result matrix
    std::cout<<"\nHere is the result: \n";
    for (int i=0; i<rows_1; i++)
    {for (int j=0; j<columns_1; j++)
    {if (rows_1==1 and columns_1==1){std::cout<<"[ "<<result[0][0]<<" ]\n";}
    else if ((i==0 and j==0) or (i==(rows_1-1) and j==0)){std::cout<<"[ "<<result[i][j]<<" ";}
    else if ((i==0 and j==(columns_1-1)) or (i==(rows_1-1) and j==(columns_1-1))) {std::cout<<result[i][j]<<" ]\n";}
    else if (j==0){std::cout<<"| "<<result[i][j]<<" ";}
    else if (j==(columns_1-1)) {std::cout<< result[i][j] <<" |";}
    else {std::cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";}}
    }
    }
//Create another function that will do the multiplication
void multiply(){/*I will fill the function definition later*/}

//This function is for choosing the operation
void decide(){
    std::cout<<"Select an operation: \n";
    std::cout<<"1. Addition\n";
    std::cout<<"2. Subtraction\n";
    std::cout<<"3. Multiplication\n";
    std::cin >> operation;
    while ((operation!=1) and (operation!=2) and (operation!=3)){
        std::cout<<"Please enter the number of an existing operation: ";
        std::cin >> operation;}
    if (operation==1){ add(); }
    else if (operation==2){ subtract(); }
    else { multiply(); }}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    std::cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"MATRIX CALCULATOR\n";
    std::cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    while(true){decide();}
}
```

Comment: You should start formating your code so it is readable. For example like the samples in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: Please don't cram as much as you can onto a single line of code, and also use empty lines to split it up into paragraphs. That will make the code *much* more easy to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Also please show a minimal example of input that triggers the problem.

Comment: And please get rid of ALL global variables!

Comment: My debugger told me you have an index out of range in this line: `row.push_back((matrix_1[i][j] + matrix_2[i][j]));`. There are most likely many other problems, but you should start here.

Comment: ... anyway the overall design of your code is terrible, and you should probably restart from scratch. I don't think this code is salvageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `create_matrix` function is wrong. It *returns* a `std::vector < std::vector<double> >`, but your code ignores the return value.

When your call `create_matrix(matrix_1, rows_1, columns_1);`, `matrix_1` won't be changed at all.

Change the `create_matrix` function like this:

```
void create_matrix(std::vector < std::vector<double> > & matrix, int rows, int columns) {
                                                    // ^ add this
  matrix.clear();   // add this line

  ... the rest of the code is identical to your's

   // and remove the "return matrix;" at the end
}
```

And also your code is missing following includes:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
```